# Sorting a single number

Tags: mathematics, letters, computer-science

What is the only number that, when written in English, gives a sequence of letters which is sorted alphabetically?

(The original phrasing of the question was meant to be a bit less straightforward to answer, as one had to come up with a way in which a single number can be 'sorted', but you didn't like it...)

Comment: written down on its own? Couldn't understand this

Comment: What does it mean to *sort* a number? Is this computer science jargon?

Comment: This sounds rather broad. I could easily say that 10, 12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19, etc are sorted by their digits...

Comment: @L.K.: written down on its own might refer to placing the number above itself. Like how `8` can be created with 2 `0`'s, although that might be a bit far fetched.

Comment: @Silenus Obviously sorting refers to seeing which postcode/ZIP code it belongs to, then seeing whether the corresponding locality is alphabetical (contains only letters). :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess that the answer you are looking for is ...

> ... **forty**.
>
>  It is the only number whose letters are sorted alphabetically when written in English.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

> **ONE**,
>
> whose letters are sorted in *reverse* alphabetical order when written in English.

Answer (score 2):

There are more possibilities:

- trivial:

  > $e$, $i$
- in a reverse alphabetical order:

  > $\pi$ (= *pi* when written down in English), 0 (if written down as *oh*)